# JUnit - Java project structure

Tags: java, junit, import, package

I have the following directory structure:

```
project/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
project/junit-4.12.jar
project/build/
project/ija/ija2016/HomeWork2Test.java
project/ija/ija2016/homework2/model/cards/Card.java
project/ija/ija2016/homework2/model/cards/CardDeck.java
project/ija/ija2016/homework2/model/cards/CardStack.java
project/ija/ija2016/homework2/model/board/AbstractFactorySolitaire.java
project/ija/ija2016/homework2/model/cards/FactoryKlondike.java
```

The HomeWork2Test.java was given to us (I cannot edit this one) and contains tests for the other classes. In the header it has these imports:

```
package ija.ija2016.homework2;

import ija.ija2016.homework2.model.board.AbstractFactorySolitaire;
import ija.ija2016.homework2.model.board.FactoryKlondike;
import ija.ija2016.homework2.model.cards.Card;
import ija.ija2016.homework2.model.cards.CardDeck;
import ija.ija2016.homework2.model.cards.CardStack;
```

So I made the Card, CardStack and CardDeck classes into a package by specifying:

```
package ija.ija2016.homework2.model.cards;
```

in each of the files.

And the AbstractFactorySolitaire and FactoryKlondike have:

```
package ija.ija2016.homework2.model.board;
```

Now we are supposed to run the tests in the HomeWork2Test.java class using JUnit. However, when I try to run the following command from the project folder:

```
javac -cp junit-4.12.jar -d build ija/ija2016/homework2/HomeWork2Test.java
```

I get errors telling me that the:

```
package.ija2016.homework2.model.cards does not exist
package.ija2016.homework2.model.board does not exist
```

I don't exactly understand how to fix the project structure. Also how do I run the JUnit test?

Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you are mixing concepts (compiling and running junit tests)

- 1st you need to compile your Classes (let's compile them to build
  dir):`javac -d build ija/ija2016/homework2/model/cards/*.java ija/ija2016/homework2/model/board/*.java`
- 2nd you need to compile your test class (you will need to add to classpath what you just compiled and the junit.jar dependency): `javac -d build -cp build;junit-4.12.jar ija/ija2016/HomeWork2Test.java`
- Now you can run your test class (in order to run you need to add to the classpath the build dir and the jar dependencies): `java -cp build;junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ija.ija2016.HomeWork2Test`

If you want to know more check [JUnit 4 Doc](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki)

if you are using Linux or MacOS use ":" instead ";" between dirs in classpath